# laravel pivot table unique

Tags: php, sql, laravel

order_id....product_id....product_quantity....created_at....updated_at

this is my pivot table...In my OrderRequest table I want to assign product_id  as unique. But when I write like this;

```
public function rules()
    {            
        return [
                'product_id' => 'unique:order_product,product_id'
                ];
   }
```

I encounter a problem. product_id becomes unique. but not only in an order, it becomes totally unique. I want to use this product_id in other orders but I can't. what can I do? How can I assign product_id as unique for each order_id values?

Comment: You can acheave this with editing the pivot migration and add this line `$table->primary(['order_id', 'product_id']);` and if you want you can remove the `id` column from the pivot table. And don't forget to do `artisan migrate:refresh` !!

Comment: that's ok but I need something else. In request form, when I select a product twice, I should get an error message. When I try as you said, it doesn't give me an error message, just saves the last option of the same product to database.

Comment: Take a look on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199441/unique-name-rule-validation-based-on-pivot-table-laravel) it can helps you, let me know if you need some expainations :)

Comment: I know that post. but it is different. at that example the user is static but in my example, orders change. order_id is created in controller. so it is useless

Comment: Can you elaborate more details to fully understand your need, how do you select products? in your controller you get a list of chosen products or what exactly ? ...

Comment: In my view, I create an order. In this order, I choose products and their quantities and attributes. then, I save this order in my database. the problem is; if I accidentally choose a product twice in my order, I want to get  error after I click save button. so I can fix my order and prevent multiple records for a product in my order.

Comment: what about the second question : in your controller you get a list of chosen products or what exactly ?

Comment: in my controller, I get ids of chosen products then save them to pivot table.

Comment: $product_id[$i]= $request->input('product_list'.$i);

Comment: `$order->product()->updateExistingPivot($product_id[$i], array(     'product_quantity' => $product_quantity[$i], 'product_status' => $product_status[$i], 'updated_at' => Carbon::now() ));`

Comment: So why don't you iterate over the product ids `$request->input('product_list'.$i);`, bfore any statement, and if you find out a product_id twice throw an exception or redirectBack with errors or with a flush message ??

Comment: you mean, when I get the same ids , it will throw an exception and give me error message. which commands can we use for that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I have ended up the issue and it works now...

this is a part of my view;

```
<div class="grid1">
   {!! Form::label('product_list'.$product_row, Lang::get('home.Select Product')) !!}         
</div>
<div class="grid2 searchDrop"> 
   {!! Form::select('product_list[]', $product_list, null, ['style'=>'width:150px;'])!!}
```

and this is part of my controller;

```
public function store(OrderRequest $request)
    {
      $order = Order::create( $request->all());

      $product_list= $request->input('product_list'); 
      $product_quantity = $request->input('product_quantity');
      $product_status = $request->input('product_status' );

            /* attach pivot table */
      $order->product()->attach($product_list);

      /* get the product list as array */              
      foreach($product_list as $key => $product_id)
      {   
        $order->product()->updateExistingPivot($product_id, array(
                        'product_quantity' => $product_quantity[$key], // product_quantity is array
                        'product_status' => $product_status[$key], // product_status is array
                        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
                        ));
      }              

           flash(Lang::get('home.The order has been created!'));
         return redirect(url('/admin/orders/details',$order->id))->with('flash_message');
     }
```

this is my OrderRequest;

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'customer_id' => 'required',
            'product_quantity.*' =>'not_in:0',
            'product_list' => 'product_unique',  //custom validation in AppServiceProvider
       ];
    }
```

and this is my AppServiceProvider;

```
public function boot()
    {
       Validator::extend('product_unique', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                if ( count(array_unique($value))!=count($value) ) {
                    return false;
                }
            return true;
        });
    }
```

Finally, in my validation.php I added;

```
"product_unique" => "Please select a product only once!",
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller assuming that you call `saveProducts` method so :

```
function saveProducts($request){
    validateProductList($request->input('product_list'))
    $order->product()
          ->updateExistingPivot($product_id[$i], 
                array( 
                    'product_quantity' => $product_quantity[$i], 
                    'product_status' => $product_status[$i], 
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now() ));
    // ....
}

function validateProductList($productIds){
    if(isProductIdDuplicated($productIds)){
        $error = 'You have a duplicated product in your Order, please edit it'
        return redirectBack()-withError();
    }
}

function isProductIdDuplicated($productIds){
    $occureces_array = productIds();
    foreach($productIds as $id){
        if(++$occureces_array[$id] > 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in your view you have access to this `$error` variable.

Comment: Is that reponds to your needs ?